# SSIS: How to get the number of updated and deleted rows in an audit?

Tags: ssis

Imagine that you want to save in a variable the number of rows the were updated or deleted in a table.
‌
This is the steps that i did:
First, in the Control flow i created a Data Flow Task. 
Them, in the Data Flow, i created a source(in my case is a excel file), then i proceeded to create two variables to count those rows- countDeleted and countUpdated, then connected the variables to two  row count transformations, and them connected my destination (OLE DB).

Now in the control flow, what do i do??
Create a SQL execute task?? or a Script task?? What is the best way to do it?? What is the piece of code to use??

Thanks for youy help.
P‌S: i only have 4 weeks off SSIS, sorry for my noobieness :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OLD DB destination *only* inserts. It can't UPDATE or DELETE

What's your logic for updating or deleting?

If you're just starting out and reading about doing things in SSIS you will eventually find advice to use the `OLE DB Command` to perform row by row delete and inserts.

In my opinion this is to be avoided. It does not scale (works fine for small recorsets then fails for large recordsets), and it is difficult to maintain parameter mappings in the OLE DB Command. Although you should try it anyway to familiarise yourself with it.

My advice is to load the Excel data into a staging table, perform batch `DELETE` and `UPDATE` statements to load the data and use `@@ROWCOUNT` to capture the records updated.

For example;

Your existing described dataflow can be used to load into a table called `StagingTable`

Before your dataflow you should run an Execute SQL Task (This is in the Control Flow pane, not the Data Flow pane) that clears the staging table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE StagingTable;
```

So first get that working - repeatedly running your package clears the staging table then loads Excel into it without creating duplicates

This in itself is a challenge as Excel is a terrible data interchange format.

Once you have that working, you add an execute SQL task to the end that runs some SQL that deletes the records you want and captures the count. For example:

```
DELETE FROM MyFinalTable WHERE PriamryKey IN (SELECT PrimaryKey FROM StagingTable);
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Then you follow the instructions here to load that back to your SSIS variable

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/03/rowcount-for-execute-sql-statement.html

What are you doing with this row count? Are you writing it to a logging table? Save 
yourself the bother of pulling it back into an SSIS variable and just write it directly:

```
DELETE FROM MyFinalTable WHERE PriamryKey IN (SELECT PrimaryKey FROM StagingTable);

INSERT INTO LogTable(Table,Operation,Type)
SELECT 'MyFinalTable','Delete', @@ROWCOUNT;
```

In my experience it is not a good idea to build convoluted logic into SSIS packages if you can instead do in a database. Although it does depend on the person who has to eventually maintain it. Hopefully you can appreciate that this T-SQL approach is a more straightforward code based approach as opposed to having to dig around in property pages and events and other places inside SSIS packages.

Comment: I want to save the row count in a Audit table, but i dont jnow how to do it. Is it possible to use a Exectue SQL Task with a trigger statement, that will get the number of rows that were updated or deleted?

Comment: "I don't know how do it" is not something I can help with. Please go through my answer bit by bit and ask a specific question about anything you have problems with.

Comment: What you need to do _first_ is load your excel file into a table.

Comment: @LuisAmaro did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using an Execute SQL Task for the updates and deletes?  As @Nick.McDermaid mentioned, using an OLE DB Command within a Data Flow presents various issues when performing DML.  You can find the number of rows updated, inserted, or deleted in a table through an Execute SQL Task by using the `ExecValueVariable` property of this task.  Set the variable that will hold the row count to this property and it will return the number of affected rows.  Note that is will only return the number of rows impacted by the last statement in the Execute SQL Task, regardless of batches (i.e. `GO` separators) are in the component.